# Is the dynamic programming pairwise alignment algorithm considered greedy?

Tags: dynamic-programming, bioinformatics

I'm a freshman in Computer Science and I'm studying bioinformatics sequence alignment algorithms.
My understanding of a greedy algorithm is one that takes the best decision for a particular instance in order to find a general best decision. By that definition, would the basic dynamic programming pairwise alignment algorithm be considered greedy?

Answer (score 2):

No. Rather, the DP algorithm for pairwise sequence alignment<sup>1</sup> is an instance of [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). What makes it superior to naïve exhaustive search is that

1. it abandons potential solutions as soon as it can prove that it is going to be sub-optimal (each field in the DP matrix considers only the optimal previous sub-alignment), and
2. it computes partial results only once and reuses them — that’s the “dynamic programming” aspect of it.

There are other, greedy algorithms for pairwise sequence alignment. These will first find so-called perfect “seed matches” between a query and a database, and then extend those outwards using one of several strategies. They thus explore locally optimal solutions but aren’t (in general) guaranteed to find a global optimum. This is for instance what the [BLAST algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) is doing.

---

<sup>1</sup> By which I’m assuming you mean the [Needleman–Wunsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) or [Smith–Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) or some minor variation.

Comment: I think it's pretty misleading to call quadratic-time DP alignment algorithms "exhaustive search" or "brute force" -- if they are considered to be brute force, then what exact algorithm would not be?  The underlying exponential-time recursion, OTOH, I would call brute force.

Comment: @j_random_hacker But I didn't call it “brute force”. And it *is* enumerating all possible solutions (they're all in the DP matrix). So that's pretty much by definition exhaustive.

Comment: Wait, no, I think I agree. Damn. I'm gonna correct this tomorrow.

Comment: Your "exhaustive search" link is to a Wikipedia page called "Brute-force search".  DP doesn't enumerate all possible solutions, rather just a subset that is known (by cleverly exploiting properties of the problem) to contain all optimal solutions; specifically, DP will never consider a solution that begins with a suboptimal solution to a subproblem (here defined by a pair of prefixes of the 2 input strings).  Maybe there's no 100% satisfying definition, since to me, branch and bound could be called exhaustive search, despite similarly avoiding enumerating some solutions.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Take a look. I think the more correct classification would be “backtracking”, which is a modification of exhaustive search. Branch & bound would also fall under this category, as far as I’m concerned.